# file path reference in Typescript language

Tags: typescript, path

```
MainDir
|_bin
|_config
|_source > myfile.ts
```

I'm new to typescript. I need to reference a file in a different folder. I created a new folder Folder1 under config and it has a file f1.py.

```
MainDir
|_bin
|_config
|     |_Folder1 > f1.py
|_source > myfile.ts
```

This line in myfile.ts works if I move Folder1 directly under MainDir:

```
const f1_path = 'Folder1';
```

I tried this but it errs:

```
const f1_path = '../config/Folder1';
```

Please suggest the cleanest way of accomplishing this. I also played around with imports and still.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood the question, but if you want to get path to the specific file then you should add the file name and format.

```
'../config/Folder1/f1.py'
```

In any case, you can look at `path` documentation in nodejs.
https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#pathjoinpaths